# Nature of the call method on Function.prototype

Tags: javascript

Is the [[Call]] function on function objects the very same call function used for controlling the receiver of function invocations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, [[Call]] is an [internal method](http://es5.github.io/#SpecOp) (for specification purposes only). It's defined for [user-created functions](http://es5.github.io/#x13.2.1) or [bound functions](http://es5.github.io/#x15.3.4.5.1), but can also be implemented on host objects.

The [`Function.prototype.call` method](http://es5.github.io/#x15.3.4.4), an actual language-accessible object, is different from it, though it invokes [[Call]].